# ngCordova AdMob Plugin implemention

Tags: cordova, admob, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I would like to implement adMob in my ionic projet.

Therefore I'm having a look at the ngCordova projet which is including an [adMob plugin](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/adMob/).
But there aren't any implementation sample available yet...

Did anyone already use that plugin from ngCordova and show me a working code sample ?

Comment: Will this work for you? https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/06/using-admob-ionicframework/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used the tutorial from https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/06/using-admob-ionicframework/ to implement admob.
This wasn't working in my project.

So I started a brand new (clean) workspace before implementing the admob network.
 And that simply did it !

Answer (score 2):

The steps to use Admob with Ionic framework would be:

1. Add *com.admob.google* plugin:

   `ionic plugin add com.admob.google`
2. Add the following script to `www/index.html` (you will not find the `angular-admob.js` file in development, as it is added after preparing each platform):

   `<script src="lib/angular-admob/angular-admob.js"></script>`
3. Show admob ads:

-

```
angular.module('myApp', ['admobModule'])
.run(['admobSvc', function (admobSvc) {
  admobSvc.createBannerView({ publisherId: "YOUR_PUBLISHER_ID" });

  // Handle events:
  $rootScope.$on('admob:' + admobSvc.events.onAdOpened, function onAdOpened(evt, e) {
    console.log('adOpened: type of ad:' + e.adType);
  });
}]);
```

Here you can find the complete example: [admob with ionic framework](https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova/wiki/Angular.js,-Ionic-apps).